# How to extend the timeout period on an AX Inbound Transformation

Tags: wcf, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics

I have a .NET assembly performing a transformation on a GeneralJournal import file in MS Dynamics AX 2012

Occaisionally I'm getting an error reported relating to a timeout (Looks like a WCF error)

I cannot see in the port setup where to configure any timeout settings.

Anyone know?

```
The request failed with the following error:  

This request operation sent to net.tcp://SERVERNAME/DynamicsAx/Services/GeneralJournalPayroll 
did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:05:00).  
The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  

This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service 
was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout 
(by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) 
and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.
```

Comment: Any news on that? and also were you able to setting OperationTimeout as stated in the error?

Answer (score 2):

To edit the WCF configuration of a port go to System administration > Setup > Services and Application Integration Framework > Inbound Ports.
Select your port - it has to be deactivated to be able to edit the configuration.
Then click Configure > go to Bindings > set timeout values.